# CSS flexbox wrapping and breaking

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I build this grid system in flexbox?

I have the following markup:

```
<section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</section>
```

which I want to display like this:

[image: Mockup]

The rules are:

- always 2 columns
- cells in rows should be the same height (dynamic, based on content)
- no requirement for rows to be the same height as each other
- separator rows should take 2 columns, and start in the leftmost column

I can get everything working except making the separators break properly by simply doing:

```
section
{
    width: 800px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
 }

div
{
    width: 350px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What about assigning 100% width to the separator, and making sure that the flex parent allows wrapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible way:

```css
section {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
section > div {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  background-color: blue;
  /*for the demo*/
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

section > .separator
{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
</section>
```